# sql injection when single quote in input is always replaced with double quote

Tags: sql, sql-injection

Suppose sql query invoked by the login form is:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name ='user input data' AND Pass ='user input data'
```

Now all single quotes in user input data are replaced with double single quotes (in other words, ' is replaced with ''.).

I can think of this possible sql injection: set user as the intended user and set the password as '\' or 1=1

but I can't think of how I am going to avoid the last ' from disrupting my sql injection.

Comment: SQL Injection might happen if you're using badly designed dynamic code. This won't cause any issues.

Comment: Are you trying to commit SQL Injection or prevent others from doing it in your own application(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding the last `'` from disrupting your SQL injection is as simple as using a comment, for example (`--` works great for single-line SQL). Alternatively, you can always add something like this:

```
someHack and '' = '
```

Now, is it possible to get around your single-quote to double-quote replacement? That most likely depends heavily on the actual SQL variant and the SQL engine you're using. For example, some SQL engines might treat endlines in input in a way that would give you trouble. Unicode is very likely to give you trouble as well, with its very complicated rules. In particular, if parts of your code are unicode aware and others aren't, it's quite easy to pass a harmless unicode character to someone who expects ASCII, and actually *use* your replacement to add the (unescaped) quote. In case you think this is a weird edge case, it's actually a very real and used SQL injection vector for PHP programmers who thought `replace` (or `addslashes`) is good enough to prevent SQL injection :D

If possible, try to use parameters instead of slapping text together. It will likely help your performance as well :) The simplest way to avoid parser bugs is to avoid using the parser.